# Officejet 6600 on Windows Server 2008 x64

Tags: drivers, windows-server-2008, hp-officejet

I have an OfficeJet 6600 which won't be installed on Windows Server 2008 x64.
I've contacted HP-support and they said that they're not allowed to support Windows Server 2008. 
So now I'm asking you guys.

When I download the installation-file from HP.com and pick '2008 x64', the installation says that the system is not supported. But I know that I've successfully installed the driver once before.

Can anyone help? Or know where I can find the drivers in a ZIP?

Comment: I think you need to be more firm on your stance.  Windows Server 2008 is currently supported by Microsoft.  Its not really shocking HP has horrible support for their software.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Found it rather easily I think</strike>

http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareCategory?os=4024&lc=en&cc=us&dlc=en&sw_lang=&product=5304873#N183

Try this:

1. load the original CD in the CD/DVD drive or download from the HP site
2. make sure the printer is connected to the usb port and has microsoft usb drivers installed you will know if this setup because when you go to the device mgr the imaging section (scanner) will say HP OJ6600(USB) and below in the usb section of device mgr you will see "usb composite device"
3. open the HP printer files location. the location is :\pathtodrivers\OJ6600
4. scroll through the files unil you come to windows installer package file named "OJ6600x64"
5. right click and select "troubleshoot compatibility" you will see the screen pop up and say "skip version check"
6. on that same screen click "test settings"
7. your software will begin loading
8. select "keep these settings" and ignore the compatibility warning
9. configure and test your printer
10. enjoy dont worry about the popup that says "configure your IP address" it will not stop you from printing from the usb if you have wireless go ahead and set that up and you will be able to see it when you want to add a network printer.

hope this helps

Comment: Yup. That's the drivers that don't work. The installation makes an OS-check and Windows Server 2008 isn't on the list. That is why I contacted HP-support in the first place.